# google calender not getting displayed in chrome and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, iframe, integration-testing, google-calendar-api

I have the following iframe for my google calendar:

```
<div>
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=bdeesh%40gmail.com&ctz=America/New_York" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

It displays properly on w3 online browser and firefox. But in explorer the following error occurs:

```
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, 
the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.
```

and in chrome it doesnt even show up. Is there a way to circumvent this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I need to make it public before it can show up on browsers. It showed up on firefox because I had gmail open on a tab. I opened W3 in firefox too.